# What are the ASDoc tool alternatives?

Tags: actionscript-3, asdoc

I have been Using the ASDoc tool. You can see [here](http://gazman-sdk.com/docs/) the result.

The main problem is that its using the same url address for all the documents. So if I want to tell some one look at Group documintation. I can't give him a direct link.

Can I fix it? If not what are the alternatives? How do I generate Action Script code documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't give him a direct link.

Actually you can. [DragSignal](http://gazman-sdk.com/docs/index.html?com/gazman/ui/drag/signals/drag/DragSignal.html)

ASDoc is great tool, and have many options, check [all available tags](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ff6.html), There is tag for AS3 code examples.